# Web Forms Project Consuming Web Api 2 Project in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In my solution, I am creating new Web Api 2 project to migrate my services in another Web Forms project.

My question is:

Is there any way (best way) to use my new Web Api project in my Web Forms project when I am debugging?

Actually I have to start my Web Api (without debbuging), after, I am able start my Web forms and use my web api. It is unproductive.

I have tried to make this works with Pre-build event, but i do not know if I did something wrong.

PS.: I do not need the both projects running in debug mode.

Comment: Check multiple startup projects in VS solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: I changed the tags. Thanks a lot. @leppie

Comment: @leppie: Where is the correct place to do this question?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/